# Understanding smartctl output for nvme ssd

Tags: ssd, nvme, smart

I am not sure to understand the output of the command `smartctl -a`, in particular the line `Percentage Used`. Note: I don't have any problem. My question is: is this output reliable ?

For a 5-year old nvme (Samsung SSD 960 EVO 500GB), I obtain :

```
sudo smartctl -a /dev/nvme0n1
(...)
Available Spare:                    100%
Available Spare Threshold:          10%
Percentage Used:                    1%
```

For a NEW nvme (Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 2TB) on another PC, I obtain

```
sudo smartctl -a /dev/nvme0n1
(...)
Available Spare:                    100%
Available Spare Threshold:          10%
Percentage Used:                    0%
```

It would mean that `Percentage Used` is the percentage of life used. It seems to me strange that a 5 year old nvme has 99% of remaining life.

Comment: You might want to see:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/652631/111521